# Adaptive Huffman Java-Assigning 1s and 0s

Tags: java, huffman-code

I am trying to work out an efficient way of assigning 0s and 1s to an existing adaptive huffman tree.All I have is a Node with dependent children.The recursive method I am trying to apply to the solution is written below(not a working one).I want to be able to return a string of 0s and ones for a specific number held in the Node data field a the time.I am not sure what conditions I am missing here.Basically the string should be a "sum" of 0s and ones(right edge =1, left one =0).The traverse starts at the root and terminates at the desired node(where data==specific data)Any suggestions will be appreciated.[Adaptive huffman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtWdJ.jpg)- the rules of the algorithm are:Read in the symbol ie.:7 to a tree that already has one empty node.Then -every single time a new symbol is read in, create two nodes right one is the one containing data and the left one is the new empty node.Also The order is decreasing right to left.When the same symbol appears in a stream, then we only update the weight(which is the frequency -"1"=one occurrence).Siblings property to be maintained-if a sibling node with a smaller order (the one on the left) has a greater weight than the sibling node with the greater order(on the right)-then they need to be swapped, including subtrees. The ORDERS however will remain-so if for example we shift left one(order 124) with the right one(order 125)-the new right node will still have the order of 125.

```
public String bc(Node n, int data){
String s=new String();
if(n!=null){
    if(n.getData()==data){
    s=s+0;
    return s;}
    else if(!n.isLeaf()&&tn.)s=s+0;//This is the point I am stuck at
    bc(n.getLeftChild(),data);
    bc(n.getRightChild(),data);

}

}


return s;
```

}

```
public class Node {

private int order;// root has the highest order
private int weight;//frequency
private int data;//symbol
private int code;//part of a codeword
private TreeNode LeftChild,RightChild;
```

Comment: It would help to include the `Node` class.  The point where you are stuck at needs to compare `data` and decide to traverse left or right.  You could do this by recursively calling `bc` with either the left or right node.  Depending on which one you are calling, add a '1' or a '0'.

Comment: Thanks John16384.Now I added the field 'code' within the node but I still dot know how to traverse the tree in order to end up with a String of 0s and 1s from the root to the desired node only.

Comment: Which one contains the huffman code that decides how to traverse the tree, `data` or `code` ?

Comment: The 'code' is the one holding 0 or 1.Thanks

Comment: Sorry. this question is just too unclear.  It seems to me you can just find the Node (by looking at all Nodes) that matches `data` and then grab its `code` field to get the result.  Unless the tree is sorted in some fashion so a comparison with `data` would make sense to determine left or right, I don't see how you could traverse this to get "ones and zeroes".  Try clarifying the question further, perhaps with a drawing or something.

Comment: To make it clear : Every node in the tree (the root node can be disregarded by changing int code to String code -) has a value 0 or 1 in the field code.The root node is created at first.The rules of assigning nodes to left or right are following FGK algorithm.I think that In a static huffman this is not an issue as we now all probabilities from the start.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this: how would you find the result if you had to do it on paper or tell me in words?  I can help you with the code, but not if there is no way to achieve the result.

Comment: Ok-To find the result I would start from the root and traverse the whole tree rejecting the nodes and edges that are not the shortest path.Every single time I would compare the "data of the node ".I am making a drawing as we speak.

Comment: I have included the image and the algorithm description.The aim is to start at the root node, "collect" the only 0s and 1s that lead to the desired node.Also-the order means the maximum number of symbols(chars) used in the input stream.

Comment: I still don't quite get it.  You say you have an existing tree, but with FGK you start with only an empty node (for both encoding or decoding).  So it seems to me you actually want to implement the FGK algorithm and you want to encode characters as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding ... is that correct?

Comment: By saying that I have got a tree I meant that I have got a working implementation of an algorithm that read and assigns symbols according to the rules-the only bit I am missing is the extracting 0s and 1s from the tree.I definitely missed something here...not sure what exactly.Yes this is FGK not the Vitter method as described in wikipedia.

Comment: It looks like I should output 0s and 1s at the point of creation of the node and keep updating it afterwards-just how to store them and keep them updated?.I think I should drop the traversal idea from before.

Comment: I think I know how to deal with this now.I should keep track of the entire path for every node in the actual Node.I shall try and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution is to keep a codeword string in every Node field.Keep it updated when adding another node: copying the codeword that is to be extended + add the new 0 or 1 depending on the side of the node.When applying "shift" function in the encoding the codeword of the swapped nodes should NOT be copied-same as the order.